# WindowsForms and Mono. Limitations of the minimum window size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

With a library .NET it works, but not with Mono.

Problem: 
Need to make the form borderless (FormBorderStyle = none) and the 50 to 50. install MaximumSize 50, 50, but the width of the reason is all the same 100. less is being done. Then install MinimumSize 50, 50, and then I get the desired result in .NET, but when I run under Linux, then all the same width greater than 100 and does not want to diminish.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just set the `Size` of the form, not Minimal or MaximalSize

Comment: When i set MaximumSize and MinimumSize to 50;50, then Size automaticaly set to 50;50